# How to access skmaps map file from Device storage instead of skmaps.zip

Tags: java, android

Since it is going to increase the size of app, I need to access the map without keeping assets to my code. Kindly help me out of this.Below is my code......

```
 SKLogging.writeLog(TAG, "Initialize SKMaps", SKLogging.LOG_DEBUG);
            startLibInitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            checkForSDKUpdate();
            SKMapsInitSettings mapsInitSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
            mapsInitSettings.setMapResourcesPath("/storage/emulated/0/SKMaps.zip");

//            int storage = skStorageManager.addStoragePath("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.skobbler.com/files/SKMaps/PreinstalledMaps");
//            skStorageManager.changeStoragePath(storage);
            mapsInitSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECTIVITY_MODE_OFFLINE);
            mapsInitSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(
                    "/storage/emulated/0/SKMaps.zip/PreinstalledMaps/v1/20160426/package/");
          //  mapsInitSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(String.valueOf(storage));
            SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(), this, mapsInitSettings);
```

This is the error it shows if i remove assets folder and try to access it from device....

```
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo D/SKMaps: SKPrepareMapTextureThread----Copy Asset SKMaps.zip
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/SKMaps.zip/SKMaps.zip: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.a(SourceFile:177)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.a(SourceFile:138)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.run(SourceFile:94)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo W/System.err:   ... 5 more
02-09 16:21:52.607 15406-15448/com.skobbler.sdkdemo E/SKMaps: TAG---- Failed preparing map textu
```

Comment: please include some code

Comment: This is my code where it getting access from assets.

Comment: @nischay-sIngh You need to add it on question by editing it not on answer

Comment: Sorry i am new to here so not aware of it....hope this time i added it properly so kindly suggest me some answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue now you can access the SKMaps.Zip folder from your external device storage follow these steps and change some code :

1.In you SplashActivity.java file write this code:
 private File filePath;
in Oncreate() : filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                +"/Android/data/com.skobbler.sdkdemo/files/SKMaps/PreinstalledMaps/"); 
 SKMapsInitSettings mapsInitSettings = new SKMapsInitSettings();
            mapsInitSettings.setMapResourcesPath(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/SKMaps/");
            mapsInitSettings.setConnectivityMode(SKMaps.CONNECT`enter code here`IVITY_MODE_OFFLINE);
            mapsInitSettings.setPreinstalledMapsPath(filePath.toString());
  SKMaps.getInstance().initializeSKMaps(getApplication(), this, mapsInitSettings);

2. Copy the whole SKMaps (not SKMaps.zip) File to your external directory (use ES File Explorer).

3.clean your project and  Run.

It will start working.